# How do I get the most checked-into venues in a given city using the foursquare API?

Tags: location, foursquare

The [search API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) gives me a list of venues in the city but with no apparent order in terms of `usersCount` or `checkinsCount`. Some have a dozen, some have thousands. Is there a way to get them sorted by either of those counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to explicitly search/sort by total check-ins or total user count.

The best alternatives are to rely on [/venues/trending](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/trending) which uses realtime popularity or on [/venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) with intent=browse to get the "most significant" venues in an area.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! One thing though: if you're using the `near` parameter with a city name, instead of `ll` (lat/long), the API doesn't accept the `intent=browse` parameter. Still returns sufficiently relevant results though.

Comment: You may also want to check out the /venues/explore endpoint, which returns "recommended" venues (though these recommendations change based on time of day and a few other factors, so they're not "universal" results)